# como almacenar un listado de objetos dentro de un image.network?

Tags: flutter

Tengo una respuesta de una api dentro de una lista, y lo que quiero es recorrerla y luego ponerla dentro de un image.network para renderizar todas las imagenes en pantalla. aqui el codigo

```
body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: widget.getdogs(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final lista = (snapshot.data["message"] as List);
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: lista.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Image.network(lista[index]);
                },
              );
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: podrías indicar que error te sale con el código que pusiste?

Comment: Y si intentas hacerle un decode a snapshot.data["message"]?

Comment: como amigo no entiendo.